# Unloading JPA references

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

does jpa 2.0 have some sort of "opposite" to reference lazy load annotation? i.e. an annotation that hints to jpa that if the annotated reference is the ONLY remaining reference to the object, the target object is eligble for garbage collection if memory is running low.

i would be perfectly content with paying a performance hit if accessing a previously loaded reference, results in a subsequent loading of the same because it has been swapped out. i need such behavior because my domain is too large to keep in memory. i've been searching for this but keep coming up empty handed, making me wonder if i am approaching the problem wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> does jpa 2.0 have some sort of "opposite" to reference lazy load annotation?

The opposite of `Lazy` is `Eager`, unfortunately this is probably not what you are looking for, because these are 'fetching methods`.

> i.e. an annotation that hints to jpa that if the annotated reference is the ONLY remaining reference to the object, the target object is eligble for garbage collection if memory is running low.

No, there is no such annotation. This behavior sounds like something you don't want. This could resolve in `NullPointerException`s, `IndexOutOfBoundException`s, `LazyInitializationException`s, etc. An object is only eligible for garbage collection if the object has no reference to it. (This is not the full explanation of g.c. but this is the basic rule.)

> i would be perfectly content with paying a performance hit if accessing a previously loaded reference, results in a subsequent loading of the same because it has been swapped out. i need such behavior because my domain is too large to keep in memory. i've been searching for this but keep coming up empty handed, making me wonder if i am approaching the problem wrong.

I think you're approaching the problem in a wrong way. I know nothing about your application so it is hard to tell what you can do. If an object is not needed anymore (by your means) then you need to handle this. JPA doesn't do this for you automatically.

Comment: thanks for the answer! i realize now i should have been more specific in my question. my domain model is a too-large-to-keep-in-memory undirected graph. my client logic traverses the graph, processing the nodes as it encounters them. once a node has been processed the client logic proceeds by following one of it links to an adjacent node. given enough time, the traversal algorithm will reprocess an previously processed node.

i need to unload a processed node due to memory but an unloaded node will be needed again at some point. what would be the best way to accomplish this using JPA?